# More efficient columnar transposition decryption

Tags: javascript, cryptography

Below, I have created a rudimentary script to decipher a columnar transposition. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to determine the number of the rows in a column? Also, is there a way to build the resulting string without creating a matrix in the interim?

## Overview

Quick refresher for columnar transpositions.

### Method 1

Given a key of `3`,

the text `'Attack at dawn'` is transposed into three columns...

```
1   2   3
A   t   t
a   c   k
a   t   D
a   w   n
```

...joining each column; left->right, top->bottom; will result in the following text:

```
Aaaa tctw tkDn
```

### Method 2

Given a key `'table'`,

the text `'Attack at dawn'` is transposed into five columns (length of the key)...

```
t   a   b   l   e
A   t   t   a   c
k   a   t   D   a
w   n
```

...joining the columns, as described above, result in the following text:

```
tAkw atan btt laD eca
```

## Code

Is there a better way to determine how many rows will be present for each column?

```
function decrypt(ciphertext, key) {
    var chars   = normalizeText(ciphertext);
    var len     = chars.length;
    var isStr   = typeof key === 'string';
    var cols    = isStr ? key.length : key;
    var rows    = Math.ceil(len / cols);
    var mod     = divMod(len, cols)[1];
    var matrix  = Matrix(rows, cols, '');
    var counter = 0;
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        var remainder = mod !== 0 && col >= mod ? 1 : 0;
        for (var row = 0; row < rows - remainder; row++) {
            matrix[row][col] = chars[counter++];
        }
    }
    return (function(plaintext, startIndex) {
        return plaintext.substr(startIndex);
    }(matrix.reduce(function(result, row) {
        return result + row.join('');
    }, ''), isStr ? cols : 0));
}
```

### Demo

```js
[ [ 'Aaaa tctw tkDn'       , 3       ],
  [ 'tAkw atan btt laD eca', 'table' ]
].forEach(function(cipher) {
    println(decrypt(cipher[0], cipher[1]));
});

function decrypt(ciphertext, key) {
    var chars   = normalizeText(ciphertext);
    var len     = chars.length;
    var isStr   = typeof key === 'string';
    var cols    = isStr ? key.length : key;
    var rows    = Math.ceil(len / cols);
    var mod     = divMod(len, cols)[1];
    var matrix  = Matrix(rows, cols, '');
    var counter = 0;
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        var remainder = mod !== 0 && col >= mod ? 1 : 0;
        for (var row = 0; row < rows - remainder; row++) {
            matrix[row][col] = chars[counter++];
        }
    }
    return (function(plaintext, startIndex) {
        return plaintext.substr(startIndex);
    }(matrix.reduce(function(result, row) {
        return result + row.join('');
    }, ''), isStr ? cols : 0));
}
function divMod(y, x) {
    return [~~(y / x), y % x];
}
function normalizeText(ciphertext) {
    return ciphertext.replace(/ +/g, "").split('');
}
function Matrix(rows, cols, defaultVal) {
    defaultVal = defaultVal !== undefined ? defaultVal : 0;
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr.push([]);
        arr[i].push(new Array(cols));
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = defaultVal;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
function print(str, targetEl) {
    return (function (el) {
        return el.html(el.html() + (str || ''));
    }(targetEl || $('#out')));
}
function println(str, targetEl) {
    print((str || '') + '<br />', targetEl)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to provide a bit of a different approach. I know it does not exactly answer your questions, but I believe it makes them somewhat obsolete.

This is how I would do the decrypt:

```
function decrypt(sentence) {
    var result = '';
    var pos = 0;

    var words = sentence.split(' ');
    words = words.map(function(word) {
       return word.split(''); 
    });

    while(true) {
       char = words[pos].shift();
        if (! char) {
            break;
        }
        result += char;

        pos = pos > words.length -2 ? 0 : pos + 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

For a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/35jyyv8g/1/

Note that I left the key out, since it is not really necessary with the spaces in the input.

Answer (score 0):

For me, all it takes are two for loops, the first one with *i* going from 0 to *cols* (stricly inferior), with increments of 1, and the second loop (inside the first one) with *j* going from *i* to *len* (stricly inferior) with increments of *rows* . And the characters you want will be at the position *j* of the initial message. Of course, a better naming for *i* and *j* would be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question,

first off, your encryption approach has some serious problems:
To know the encryption key length, you just need 
`ciphertext.split(' ').length`

Worse, the cipher-text even has the key in clear text:

**t**Akw **a**tan **b**tt **l**aD **e**ca

This means @Pevara's approach is correct, and far more elegant. (It does also output the key for strings encrypted with the second method.)

My personal approach uses a bit of ES6 and is a bit more functional:

```
function simpleDecrypt2(cipher) {
    let out = '',
        parts = cipher.split(' ').map(function(part) { return part.split(''); });

    while( parts[0].length ){
       out += parts.reduce( (out,part)=>out+(part.shift()||''), '' );  
    }
    return out;
}
```

As for your first question, you could have calculated the row count by

`ciphertext.split(' ')[0].length`